# JavaScript - Select the li element with a data-id, which is equal to a specific value

Tags: javascript

In an unordered list which looks like this:

[image]

Using JavaScript, how can I select the li element with a specific data-id? for example "2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6"

Comment: The data-id is used by jQuery. Data-whatever gets loaded into the jquery element's .data. You can call it as a selector $('li').('[data-id="blabla"]') or you can iterate them .each and check if .data('id') is what you're looking for.

Comment: @joshstrike not only by jQuery. This works too (but @Yousaf has an even better selector): `document.querySelectorAll(".list__item").filter(e => e.dataset.id == "2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6")[0]`

Comment: @tucuxi wow, I've been using jq too long. I didn't know that was a native function! Good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use attribute selector

```
li[data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6"]
```

```css
li[data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6"] {
  background: #fc3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6">item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

In javascript, use `querySelector` with this attribute selector

```
document.querySelector('li[data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6"]');
```

```js
document.querySelector('li[data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6"]').textContent = 'selected';
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6">item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

So in Javascript :

```
document.querySelector("li[data-id=2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6]");
```

the li element that have data-id "2tcppVEwHLpZ0E0khCz6" will be selected.